# NodeJS: @esri/arcgis-rest-request - How to adjust Fetch options?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am looking to adjust the **Fetch request** option when making a request with **@esri/arcgis-rest-request**, but unfortunately I cannot find any documentation related to this.

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";
import FormData from "isomorphic-form-data";
import arcgisRestRequest from "@esri/arcgis-rest-request";
arcgisRestRequest.setDefaultRequestOptions({ fetch, FormData });

arcgisRestRequest.request("https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/info")
  .then(response => console.log(response));
```

When using the request method I am getting errors regarding the certificate of the NodeJS server:

```
FetchError: request to https://xxx/server/rest/self?token=xxx=json failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I would like to pass something like:

```
const fetchOptions = {
  ...
  agent:new https.Agent({rejectUnauthorized: false}),
  ...
};
```

to avoid the certificate error.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at their code](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-rest-js/blob/master/packages/arcgis-rest-request/src/request.ts#L189) it looks like you should be able to just do

```js
arcgisRestRequest.request(
  "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/info",
  {
    agent:new https.Agent({rejectUnauthorized: false})
  }
)
  .then(response => console.log(response));
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but unfortunately using that format TypeScript says that it is not allowed in the IRequestOptions and if I do a @ts-ignore on that line it still fails.  I wish they had a little better documentation